# Parse JSON string in PHP "gdata.io.handleScriptLoaded"

Tags: php, json

I am fetching the data in JSON format from YouTube
but it returns the JSON as `gdata.io.handleScriptLoaded({key:value})`;

How I can access the `key` in  php as the response is not JSON object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the answer my self.

I was passing the value into request url `script-in-json`. simplay changed it to `json`

Comment: Rana's self-answer was the solution for me as well - I was using 'script-in-json' instead of simply 'json'. I needed to know what other formats/options were available. Thanks to Rana's answer I knew what the right thing to query with Google. https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#load_the_javascript_api_and_ajax_search_module

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the suggested url params from the API docs and i went nuts trying to parse the JSON with jQuery. This worked. Thank you Rana

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = gdata.io.handleScriptLoaded({key:value});
    $res = json_decode($json);
    print $res->{'key'}; // it prints your value
```

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object`